# How to instantiate a class from string FQN in database in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to convert a legacy application to hibernate.

I have an entity that has a field, which should be instantiated to object instance based on a fully qualified name string in a database.

Consider the example below - if I have `somePackageName.FirstClass` in a database the `someObject` field should be an instance of `FirstClass`.

I guess I could use property access and persist / retrieve a string but that doesn't look very elegant to me.

I cannot use `@PostLoad` etc. - I'm using pure hibernate with spring (not JPA) - these annotations get ignored.

I know for example in MyBatis one can register a custom handler for field. Would anything similar be available in Hibernate?

I'm new to hibernate so I'm not really sure what the options are.

```
@Entity
class SomePersistentClass{
   private SomeInterface someObject; 

}
```

---

```
class FirstClass implements SomeInterface{
}
```

---

```
class SecondClass implements SomeInterface{
}
```

Comment: If you're using `@Entity`, then you *are* using JPA.

Comment: @skaffman There is a difference between using JPA annotations and using JPA APIs.  Persistence providers simply leverage the JPA defined annotations as the basic means to provide mapping metadata rather.  To most people, I would say, using JPA annotations is not "using JPA".  Rather, I think to most developers "using JPA" means using the JPA APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JPA features such as @PostLoad, etc callbacks simply by enabling the proper Hibernate event listeners.  Check the Hibernate EntityManager guide for details.

But this one is even easier.  This is the role of a Type in Hibernate.  First, you'll have to write an implementation of org.hibernate.type.Type or org.hibernate.usertype.UserType and specify that in @Type( type=... ) that handles the conversions (lots of web resources about writing custom Hibernate types).  Then annotate your 'someObject' attribute with @Type( type="your.custom.TypeImpl" )